# Change UIButton Color in CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift

I have two classes: `ViewController` and `PercentCollectionViewCell`.

When I tap on a `button1_Tap` the color is changed to blue. When I tap on a `button2_Tap`, the color of the second button turns blue, but the color of the first button does not turn back to white color.

PercentCollectionViewCell class:

```
class PercentCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstPercent: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondPercent: UIButton!
}
```

ViewController class:

```
let cellIdentifiers:[String] = ["FirstPercentCell", "SecondPercentCell"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellIdentifiers.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let collectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifiers[indexPath.item], for: indexPath) as? PercentCollectionViewCell

    collectionCell?.firstPercent?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1_Tap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    collectionCell?.secondPercent?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button2_Tap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return collectionCell!
}

@objc func button1_Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let firstPercent = sender

    firstPercent.isSelected = true;
    firstPercent.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    secondPercent.isSelected = false;
    secondPercent.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    percentage = 0.05
}

@objc func button2_Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let firstPercent = sender

    firstPercent.isSelected = false;
    firstPercent.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    secondPercent.isSelected = true;
    secondPercent.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    percentage = 0.1
}
```

Comment: I have tried. When I delete `let firstPercent = sender` the buttons no longer change the colors.

Comment: Do not duplicate your own question. Ask the first question better. You didn't ask it any better the second time than you did this time. The key point is that this needs to happen across collection view cells. Nowhere have you made that clear.

Comment: @matt I'm sorry for that. I did not know that I can't use outlet collection to change the color for the buttons from different cell. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Put your `button_Tap` function in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass.
You can get by with just one `button_Tap` action.  Hook both buttons to this function:

```
class PercentCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstPercent: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondPercent: UIButton!

    @objc func button_Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let buttonSelected = sender
        let buttonUnselected = (sender === firstPercent) ? secondPercent : firstPercent

        buttonSelected.isSelected = true
        buttonSelected.backgroundColor = .blue

        buttonUnselected.isSelected = false
        buttonUnselected.backgroundColor = .white

        percentage = (sender === firstPercent) ? 0.05 : 0.1
    }
}
```

Then either wire the buttons up in the Storyboard or set them up like this in `cellForItemAt`:

```
collectionCell?.firstPercent?.addTarget(collectionCell!, action: #selector(PercentCollectionViewCell.button_Tap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
collectionCell?.secondPercent?.addTarget(collectionCell!, action: #selector(PercentCollectionViewCell.button_Tap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

> I'm sorry, I forgot to clarify that I have the value of percentage for
>   each button tap functions. So I think I need a few functions. Also in
>   the future, there will be more buttons (up to 10).

In that case, assign your buttons to an `@IBOutlet` collection and assign unique `tag` values in the range `0...9`.  Connect each button to the outlet collection in the Storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

Then

```
@objc func button_Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttons.forEach { button in button.backgroundColor = .white }
    sender.backgroundColor = .blue
    percentage = [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5][sender.tag]
}
```

Make sure to assign the `button_Tap` action to each of your buttons.

Comment: Thank you. I tried. But the problem is still the same. I'm sorry, I forgot to clarify that I have the value of percentage for each button tap functions. So I think I need a few functions. Also in the future, there will be more buttons (up to 10).

Comment: You can assign tags to the buttons and use those as an index into an array `let percent = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0][sender.tag]` assuming tags have values of 0...3 for instance.

Comment: Try just changing the background color of the buttons and don't set `isSelected` at all.

Comment: I tried this method, but the problem is the same. The color does not change back.

Comment: I just updated the answer.  Have a look.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried everything you wrote. But the buttons do not change the color back to white when another button is selected. They remain in blue color.

Comment: I also tried this: `for button in buttons {
        if button.tag == sender.tag { sender.backgroundColor = .blue }
        else {button.backgroundColor = .white}
            
        }`. Nothing changed. The buttons do not change the color back to white.

Comment: Are you still setting `isSelected = true` or did you try not doing that.  Also, what does `print(buttons.count)` print when a button is pressed?

Comment: I'm trying without `isSelected = true`. Hmm... `print(buttons.count)` always print `1`. But `print(button.tag)` and `print(sender.tag)` shows correct button tag number.

Comment: Did you connect all the buttons in the prototype cell to the buttons outlet collection?

Comment: Yes. All outlets are connected. http://take.ms/DiG9F

Comment: @vacawama what he's not explaining is that each button is in a different collection view cell. Outlet collections won't work here. The button color needs to be changed in the data model and the cells reloaded.

Comment: @matt, I wondered if that were the case, but it doesn't fit with his code above.  The two buttons are clearly in the same cell.

Comment: @matt is right. Each button is in a different collection view cell. As I understand it, this is the reason.

Comment: Take @matt's advice in the other question.  You need to keep a model of which button is selected (could be just an `Int` in your `collectionViewController` that keeps the `indexPath.row`.  When a button is pressed, update the model and then reload the table.  In your `cellForRowAt`, check to see if the current cell's indexPath.row matches the selected row.  If so, make its button `.blue`, otherwise make it `.white`.  You also might want to set the button's tag to `indexPath.row` so that you know which button was selected in the `button_Tap` method.